# How can I jQuery select a child div element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to select a page element based on the 'id' of a parent, plus the 'class' of one of its children. This works when the child is a span element, but fails when it's a div.

How can I select the specific *#testDiv .highlightme* item below?

```
<script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#testSPAN .highlightme').css("background-color","yellow");  
        $('#testDIV  .highlightme').css("background-color","blue");  
    });  
</script>  



<p id="testSPAN">
    <span class="highlightme">
        This should highlight, and does. Good.
    </span>
</p>

<p id="testDIV">
    <div class="highlightme">
        This should highlight, but doesn't because it's in a div.
    </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `p` tag only takes inline elements, not other blocks.
`http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P`
"The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

This is the core of your problem, it is invalid HTML.

Comment: Thank you! I had div's contained within <a> and <p> tags that would display properly, but were not recognized by jquery selects. Properly formatting the block-level elements resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether it's a div or span. You can attribute a class element to any markup.

The problem is not because of your jquery code but you wrap your div element within a p 
it's not allowed in html ! :)

Answer (score 0):

What have been told here, it's true, you should not put block elements inside inline elements, but if you can't modify the html or you are not allowed, here is a little work around that will work for you...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*="test"]').each(function() {
        var bgcolor = "yellow";
        if ($(this).children('[class="highlightme"]')   ) {
            $(this).children('[class="highlightme"]').css('background-color', bgcolor);
        }
        if ($(this).next().hasClass("highlightme") == true) {
            $(this).next().attr('class', 'highlightme').css('background-color', bgcolor);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this little block of code helps you out, if you need anything else, just let me know ;)